# Can not solving Reverse accessor clashes

Tags: python, django, models, name-clash

I have a bug that I can not solve in django>=1.8,<1.9.
I merged my changes and I get this:

```
ERRORS:
archive.Booking.articles: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Booking.articles' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Booking.articles'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Booking.articles' or 'Booking.articles'.
archive.Booking.articles: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Booking.articles' clashes with reverse query name for 'Booking.articles'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Booking.articles' or 'Booking.articles'.
events.Booking.articles: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Booking.articles' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Booking.articles'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Booking.articles' or 'Booking.articles'.
events.Booking.articles: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Booking.articles' clashes with reverse query name for 'Booking.articles'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Booking.articles' or 'Booking.articles'.
```

Here is my model:

```
class Booking(events_models.AbstractBooking):
    period = models.ForeignKey('archive.Period', null=True, related_name='events', help_text='ref_artistic_period')
    distributions = models.ManyToManyField('archive.Distribution', related_name='bookings',
                                           through='archive.Booking2Distribution')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('archive:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'pk': self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_start',]
```

Here is my base class with articles field:

```
class AbstractBooking(SearchMixin, TranslationMixin, MediaMixin, PriceMixin, ImagesMixin, DownloadsMixin, AdminMixin, TicketMixin):
    ...
    articles = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Article', related_name='bookings', blank=True)
    ...
```

I tried added `articles` field to my `Booking` class like below, but without success:

```
articles = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Article', related_name='%(class)s_bookings', blank=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure AbstractBooking is actually abstract?

Comment: Remove the `related_name` from the abstract.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, because when I removed `articles` from `AbstractBooking` - I didn't got errors.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that means that AbstractBooking is abstract. Do you have `abstract=True` in the Meta class for that model?